# Python module import fails for unknown reason

Tags: python, import, importerror

I am trying to import a module in python that contains the following lines:

```
#setup.py
def isnumber(pause):
    try:
        float(pause)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

I am trying to call it like this:

```
#program.py
import setup
```

but I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rthompson@iingen.unam.mx\ralph\programas\python\scraper\release\program.py", line 4, in <module>
    import setup
  File "C:\Users\rthompson@iingen.unam.mx\ralph\programas\python\lib\setup.py", line 55, in <module>
    download_url="http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/"
  File "C:\Users\rthompson@iingen.unam.mx\ralph\programas\python\lib\distutils\core.py", line 140, in setup
    raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg
SystemExit: usage: program.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: program.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: program.py --help-commands
   or: program.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Line 55 in setup.py corresponds to `return True` in the code above.

Without the isnumber function the import works as expected.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: setup.py is already defined in the python distribution, so changing the module name fixed the problem. I don't understand why removing the function made any difference though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've decided to call your module "setup.py". This is a dangerous name to pick since it's commonly used for the build/install script for Python modules, much like the one yours already has. Pick a different name.

Comment: thanks, I just spotted that. Weird that removing this little function made the import work though.